# How do I show what emojis are in the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I was working on a discord.js server info command. So I had an idea, of showing the emojis that are in a server, though I don't know how to do that. I do know how to get the amount of emojis, but I'm not sure how to get the emojis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const emoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.array();
message.channel.send(emoji);
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answer. Try to provide an explanation of how this solves the question